# Using EXSLT to subtract dates

Tags: date, xslt, exslt, date-format

How can I use EXSLT extensions to subtract a date.

I see that there is a date-add function, but the EXSLT docs don't include any examples. I am trying to take the current date and subtract 1 month for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To subtract, add a negative durations.

See [details](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#adding-durations-to-dateTimes) in the XML Schema specification.

```
date:add($now, '-P1M')
```